# Accessing Different Singleton Data based on contents of a variable

Tags: objective-c, variables, cocos2d-iphone, singleton

I'm using cocos2d for the iPhone and I have a singleton set up to store all of the data and variables for the players and I need to know if this is possible to do,
so in pseudo code it would be something like:

```
players * playersDataManager = [players playersSaveDataManager];
selected = "sword"
name = (@"%@AttRange",selected);
AttRange = playersDataManager.name;
```

The `name` would change based on what player was selected so the `AttRange would change too. I just don't know how to set it up in real code. Here is the actual code that I'm using:

```
-(void)showAttackRange:(NSMutableString *)selected {
    players * playersDataManager = [players playersSaveDataManager];
    NSMutableString * name1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"MaxRange"];
    [name1 insertString:selected atIndex:0];

    int r = [playersDataManager valueForKey:name1];
    NSLog(@"%@%i",name1,r);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "Key-Value coding"

To use it in your example code:

```
Players * playersDataManager = [Players playersSaveDataManager];
NSString *selected = @"sword"; 
NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@AttRange", selected);
AttRange value = [playersDataManager valueForKey:propertyName];
```

Will work assuming your `Players` class has a property of type & name `AttRange swordAttRange` that is either `@synthesized` w/ default accessors, OR, if you have specified custom accessors for your properties, they follow an expected naming scheme.

(For more information on what KVC expects in terms of accessor naming schemes, read the documentation...)

Apple Documentation: [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)

EDIT: 
Using KVC to get scalar values returns an `NSNumber` object: [Apple Documentation -> KVC Scalar and Structure support](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002171-BAJEAIEE)

Comment: @stenger96 Yes, it will. Whether or not multiple instances of your object exist (or are allowed to exist) has no impact on this protocol.

Comment: Do I need to set the key, or is the key the variables name?

Comment: @stenger96 The key is the _property's_ name, yes.  Edited original answer to be a bit more explicit... let me know if that clears it up!

Comment: I'm a little confused on how to access the data in the singleton. The variable `sMaxRange` in the singleton is an `int` but when I use `int x = [playersDataManager valueForKey:name];` I get a warning `incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'id'`

Comment: @stenger96 Using KVC to get scalar values returns an `NSNumber` object: [Apple Documentation -> KVC Scalar and Structure support](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002171-BAJEAIEE)

Comment: So then I can just get the intValue from the NSNumber. Thanks!!